# How to combine two sets of data without common field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I came across a tricky SQL to see whether anyone can help

```
SELECT column1, column2 as highestNo
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN TableB
on TableA.tNo = TableB.Plan_tno
```

returned Result (it will always be one row returned)

```
column1         highestNo
J111646912      201603010576
```

```
Select Column3, Column4 
From TableB 
Inner join TableC
On TableB.key1 = TableC.plan_key
Where TableB.Column3< highestNo(get it from last set)
```

Returned result shall be

```
Column3        Column4 
201603010525   J111646547 
201603010004   B233435353 
201603010324   J435345445 
201603010570   H345353535
```

How can I combine the script and result as one piece instead of two pieces here?
so I can one set of result returned.

Comment: SQL server 2012, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
Select Column3, Column4, t.column1, t.highestNo
From TableB 
Inner join TableC On TableB.key1 = TableC.plan_key
cross join (
   SELECT column1, column2 as highestNo
   FROM tableA
   INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.tNo = TableB.Plan_tno
) as t
Where TableB.Column3 < t.highestNo
```

The single record returned by the first query will be simply appended to the rest of the records returned by the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a scalar subquery;

```
Select Column3, Column4 
From TableB b Inner join
     TableC c
     On b.key1 = c.plan_key
Where b.Column3 < (select column2 as highestNo
                   from tableA a inner join
                        TableB b
                        on a.tNo = b.Plan_tno 
                  );
```

You say the subquery always returns one row.  Otherwise, I would advise using `max(column2)` in the subquery.

Comment: it is great for the help. Giorgos answer sounds better as it could return all the field from both set. thanks

Comment: @Ann . . . Your question *explicitly* asks for only the columns returned by the answer here.  You should really ask the question that you want, not some vague approximation so others have to guess at your real intentions.